# laravel default email styling is not changing

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-notification

I'm following this [guide](https://laraveldaily.com/mail-notifications-customize-templates/) to change the default email stlying. I tried to change the stylesheet inside `resources/views/mail/html/themes/default.css` but it doesn't work. I'm not creating any custom notification for auth emails.

I tried to change the content of the blade file located in the following directory, it is showing updated content, but I don't know from where it is applying to style the email.

```
resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php
```

Comment: It's been a while since i've done this. Have you tried `php artisan view:clear`?

Comment: yes I tried but it didn't work

Comment: are you sure about the directory structure and not `resources/views/VENDOR/mail/html/themes/default.css`? You may verify if in the browsers `dev-tools` if the correct `default.css` file is loaded and holds the expected changed content

Comment: yes I tried in browser, it is showing updated verison but in mail it is not applying

Answer (score 2):

## Customizing Notifications with markdown

create a copy of the `default.css` in `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes`. Something like `custom.css`

If you don't have `vendor` directory, consider to publish the `laravel-mail` tag:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

In your Notification change the css with the theme method:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->theme('custom')
        ->subject('Demo Subject')
        ->markdown('mail.invoice.paid', ['url' => $url]);
}
```

## Customizing auth mails

While generating the auth using `make:auth`, it will generate the required views in the `resources/view/auth` folder.

The files will have the corresponding  layouts tag

```php
<x-guest-layout>

  {{-- some content --}}

</x-guest-layout>
...
```

You can customize the `guest-layout` from the `resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php` or create a new `custom.blade.php` file and change the tags in your mail templates:

```php
<x-custom-layout>

  {{-- some content --}}

</x-custom-layout>
```

Comment: I don't want to create separate notifications. I just want to use the built-in auth mails but only customize the styling.

Comment: well, in this case you will find the templates in `resources/views/auth`. Open one the templates and check the layout tags `<x-guest-layout>...</x-guest-layout>`. Unter `resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php` you'll find the guest layout and it's css file. The `default.css` does not apply on the `auth mails`.

Comment: I didn't see these files on my side. I'm using my own views for auth pages for front end. There are no components available

Comment: I don't want to customize auth pages styling. I am talking about auth emails

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not actually use any email template, instead it builds the email directly using `MailMessage` like this

```php
return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
            ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
            ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
```

So to override this, in any of your Service Providers, I will go with `AuthServiceProvider`, add the following:

```php
// use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
// ...


ResetPassword::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
            $email = $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset();

            
            $emailResetUrl = url(route('password.reset', [
                    'token' => $token,
                    'email' => $email,
                ], false));
            
            // this is where you generate your own email
            return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
                ->view('email.auth.reset-password', [
                    'url' => $emailResetUrl
                ]);
        });
```

Or you learn more from this article, https://medium.com/@josephajibodu/how-to-customize-laravel-fortify-authentication-email-templates-21b6a315e279